# Duplicate entry error in ManyToManyField in Django model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, postgis, django-migrations

Duplicate entry error in ManyToManyField in Django model. We are using unique_together option in the Meta class but that is not associated with this field.

When I try to add a new entry to Staff model the error occurs Staff and Location UID already exists.

This is my model:-

```py
class Staff(models.Model):
    

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='merchant_staff')
    stores = models.ManyToManyField(Location, null=True, blank=True)
    pin = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1000), MaxValueValidator(9999)])

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('pin', 'merchant'), ('shortname', 'merchant'),)
```

this is my error:-

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "merchants_staff__staff_id_locatio_2fb867d4_uniq"
```

Comment: The error likely originates from `Merchant` or `Location` can you share these models?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
Key (staff_id, location_id)=(fb29cddb-36ae-4d6a-9a20-e067c83d02d3, a4c36824-21c0-4c88-8edb-9029731bb49f) already exists,... this is the error when I create an entry to this model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The ManyToManyField is not related to Merchant, It's only related to Staff and Location, and can't share the Location model because its very big.

Comment: but why are you certain this has something to do with the m2m field?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem look at the error message I passed in the comment section, that shows staff_id and location_id already exist. In this case, I think the issue is occurring from Location foreign key, Which means it's ManyToManyField.

Comment: But your field is named `stores` and you can not put a unique constraint on an m2m field, since a database can only check uninqness over its rows, an m2m has no specific column in the table, it creates a junction table. So it seems the contraint is either out of sync with your model, or it is raised by another model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If add an entry without store there will be no errors but If I pass store id the error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

```html
staff_instance = Staff.objects.get(id=staff_id)  # Replace staff_id with the actual ID of the staff member
location_instance = Location.objects.get(id=location_id)  # Replace location_id with the actual ID of the location

# Check if the association already exists
if not staff_instance.stores.filter(id=location_id).exists():
    staff_instance.stores.add(location_instance)
```

Comment: This was working fine before but now It's raising this error, I want to know why.